# How to add a link to selectpicker items?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I want any option of menu to refer to some page when get clicked in the [angular selectpicker](https://github.com/joaoneto/angular-bootstrap-select). How can I do this?

I tried something like this, but to no avail

```
<option><a href="">First Option</a></option>
```

Here's [Codepen](http://codepen.io/Alexnotonfire/pen/JYpZZq) sandbox.

**HTML**

```
<html ng-app="selectDemoApp"> 
<body>
  <div role="main">
    <div class="container">
      <section ng-controller="SelectCtrl">
        <div class="page-header">

          <select class="selectpicker">
            <option>Mustard</option>
            <option>Ketchup</option>
            <option>Relish</option>
          </select>

        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**JS**

```
angular.module('selectDemoApp', [ 'angular-bootstrap-select', 'angular-bootstrap-select.extra']);

function SelectCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.form = undefined;
}
```

Comment: here is the updated codepen 

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qOxgJz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this way

```
<select class="selectpicker" ng-model="changeState" ng-change="change(changeState)">
    <option value="https://google.com">Mustard</a>
    </option>
    <option value="/2.html">Ketchup</a>
    </option>
    <option value="/3.html">Relish</a>
    </option>
  </select>
```

In your controller

```
$scope.change = function(url){
  window.open('url');
}
```

Hope you will get an idea to achieve your goal..

Answer (score 1):

You can use a other logic to perform your redirection.

See the [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WQMPJE?editors=101) forked from yours.

Here it is the controller which perform the redirection :

VIEW :

```
 <select class="selectpicker" ng-model="choice" ng-change="redirect()">
            <option value="/1.html">Mustard</a></option>
            <option value="/2.html">Ketchup</a></option>
            <option value="/3.html">Relish</a></option>
 </select>
```

CONTROLLER :

```
 $scope.redirect = function()
  {
    var landingUrl = "http://" + $window.location.host +  $scope.choice;

    $window.location.href = landingUrl;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is updated codepen with your solution..  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qOxgJz

```
<select class="selectpicker" ng-change="onSelectChange()" ng-model="selectedValue">
    <option>Mustard</a></option>
    <option>Ketchup</a></option>
    <option>Relish</a></option>
</select>
```

---

```
var selectDemoApp = angular.module('selectDemoApp', [ 'angular-bootstrap-select', 'angular-bootstrap-select.extra']);
selectDemoApp.controller('SelectCtrl', ['$scope', '$window',
  function($scope, $window) {
      $scope.onSelectChange = function(){       
        if($scope.selectedValue === 'Mustard'){
           $window.open("www.google.com");
        } else if($scope.selectedValue === 'Ketchup'){
           $window.open("www.facebook.com");
        } else if($scope.selectedValue === 'Relish'){
           $window.open("2.html");
        }
      }
  }
]);
```